# Is there any way to set different price in Stripe for first and following year?

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, recurring-billing

I am creating yearly subscription plan in Stripe. 
First year will be charged $100 and next year onward will be $75.

In PayPal, I done a trick as setting 1 year Trial Period and charge $100. Then for following year, I set $75 for billion amount.

In Stripe, I could not set amount in Trial Period. Once I set a trial period in Stripe, meaning no charging at all.

So far, I went through Stripe documentation and found some of the following ways:

1. use Webhooks: setup 2 plans - $100 plan and $75 plan. Then add a webhook endpoint for "subscription_schedule.expiring". So, new subscriber will go under $100 plan first and get notified via Webhooks when the first plan is expiring. Then I need to write a function to update its plan to $75.
2. use Subscription Schedules: I am not sure this is solution for it. ([ref here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/schedules))
3. use Multiple Plans: when new subscriber come in, let assign in both plans. I will set $100 plan for "renewal_behavior=none" and set 1 year trial period for $75 plan.
4. create my own schedule task: my function will check subscription expiring date and will update to next plan if it is going to expire in 7 days.

Anyone got experience it before and what is the workaround for best way.

By the way, I am using Laravel.

Thank in advance.

Comment: first point is best way from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#first-invoice-extra

Does this help you out at all?

You could add an extra charge of $25 to the first invoice of every subscription. (And call it a "setup fee")

Comment: thank for your reply. we don't have "setup fee", it will very confuse to our customer.

Comment: Doesn't sound that confusing but ok.